# How to download invoice images from Coupa using Python

Tags: python, coupa

I have a csv file with the url for a list of invoices in Coupa. I need to use python to got to the Coupa and download the image scan PDF file to a specific folder.  I have the following code.  It runs but when I open the PDF file it comes back corrupted.  Any help would be appreciated.

```py
import requests 
file_url = "https://mercuryinsurance.coupahost.com/invoice/15836/image_scan"

r = requests.get(file_url, stream = False) 

with open("python.pdf","wb") as pdf: 
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 

         # writing one chunk at a time to pdf file 
         if chunk: 
             pdf.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Can you confirm that there are bytes that return from `requests.get()`?

Comment: Did you attempt to open that PDF only with a PDF viewer, or did you also inspect it with a hex viewer to see if it really contains a PDF?

Comment: Yes, I get bytes returned, and when I changed the type on the file from PDF to HTML, I get the login screen.

Comment: Yes, I attempted to open the PDF file directly, and it works without issue.  The only reason I am using python is because I have over 2,300 PDF files to download.